# app.js:63 Uncaught ReferenceError: GLTFLoader is not defined

Tags: javascript, three.js

When i call this in three.js const loader = new GLTFLoader(); get this error app.js:63 Uncaught ReferenceError: GLTFLoader is not defined. it is import in index.html.but got that error

```
<script src="./three.min.js"></script>
<script src="./OBJLoader.js"></script>
<script src="./GLTFLoader.js"></script>
<script src="./app.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A code like `const loader = new GLTFLoader();` only works if you import `GLTFLoader` as an ES6 module via `import` statement. When doing so, `GLTFLoader` is no part of the `THREE` namespace.

Since you are using `three.min.js`, you are not using a module based workflow but global scripts. That means `GLTFLoader` is only available under the `THREE` namespace. So changing your code to the following should fix the issue:

```js
const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
```